# Parsing Numbers and Alphbet in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to parse numbers and letters in one of my sheets.
I've been playing around with find and using trim but i'm at a loss can someone help?

I have 150A in cell A1, how can i get 150 in B1 and A in C1 using just formulas?

*edit  there will be multiple lines with different values, all will have numbers not all will have letters. i.e 200B, 300, 77D.  however there will never be the same number and same letter i.e. never 150A and 75A

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version of excel?

Comment: When I have needed this in the past I made a function for alpha, and a function for numeric, that took a string and returned only characters that fit the profile.  This function can then be called as a formula in a cell

Comment: well, if you have Excel 2013, flash fill can do this if you manually do a couple (I had to do 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for:
In B1

> =IF(ISTEXT(A1),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),A1)

In C1

> =IF(ISTEXT(A1),RIGHT(A1,1),"")

Any cell with a letter will be viewed as text.  This returns a true, so strip off the letter for your B1 result, strip off the numbers for your C1 result. Otherwise, just return A1 or and empty string.